# Implementing SSO on React-Redux app

Tags: reactjs, redux, single-sign-on, react-redux, keycloak

I'm trying to implement SSO on a React-Redux app using Keycloak as an external Identity Provider. The intent is to redirect to the IdP's login page if the user is not authenticated and after successful authentication use the access_token to access protected resources on another REST API microservice.

I tried to use Keycloak's NodeJS adapter (https://keycloak.gitbooks.io/documentation/securing_apps/topics/oidc/nodejs-adapter.html) and it is able to redirect me to the IdP for logging in and I can get the access_token but this all happens in the express-session and uses the MemoryStore. I was wondering if this is okay? Saving JWTs in the express store and retrieving them from the store while making an API call?

Or should I try doing something like saving the authentication status (JWT token) in Redux's store? Would it be better when compared with session cookies? Session cookies might be more secure but would involve accessing the store every time, right?

Above all, how can I achieve the approach where Redux store has the JWT?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OpenID Connect SSO in React-Redux app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44958133/openid-connect-sso-in-react-redux-app)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For all those who are interested, I managed to implement it in the following way:

- Load Keycloak.js (Keycloak's JS adapter) from the keycloak server
- Initialize the Keycloak Script using the configuration parameters of the client.
- Create a Reducer to fetch JWT tokens by invoking the Keycloak script when the main React component is about to be rendered.
- Add the token to the state.

Anyways, we now believe that dynamically loading Keycloak.js from the server wouldn't be a good idea and above all, this would tightly couple our app to Keycloak. We are now looking for a more generic OIDC implementation.

As for storing the token, we've thought that the Redux store might not be the best place for JWTs. We're considering saving tokens in the localStorage instead.

Hope this helps someone!

Comment: have a look at redux-oidc or the low-level library that actually does the work called oidc-client - includes JWT handling (whichever storage you want!) and Redux store updates out-of-the-box. Already answered your duplicate question as well...

Comment: @Leon, Although both redux-oidc and the oidc-client libraries seem pretty great and I tried them both but my usecase was somewhat different to what these offer. I don't have a login (or an unauthenticated page) component in my app. By default, we are targeting to protect all routes of the application and therefore things like CallbackComponent/redirect_uri are things that we can't do.

For now, I initialize the OIDC adapter in the _onEnter_ of the react-router and get stuff to work, but now I'm trying to get authorization code flow to work in a SPA to protect my client secret!

Comment: I also do not have a "landing page", and the "CallbackComponent" is protected behind all the other routes (yes, in a SPA)... ANY hit will get authenticated, the CallbackComponent just sets the localStorage/cookies correctly (and checks user's expiration amongst other things) to avoid hitting the auth server every time. All works fine here ;)

Comment: Oh! That's great then. So you have a component only to set/refresh tokens and you treat it as a CallbackComponent. That's neat.

What should be the route of such a component? And if /home is where the user initiates the login, and /callback is where we store the token from, how would the user be redirected back to where he started from? History? Please add these as an answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an [react app](https://github.com/mnadeem/react-sso-app) which demonstrate how we can integrate SSO with React Applications.

- Uses Keycloak as IDP
- OAuth 2 for SSO
- JWT as Auth Token (Which can be stored in Redux, instead of Authprovider state)
- React UI
- Node Js (Express) backend

Disclaimer : I am the owner of the repo

Comment: This looks cool. But in my case I need React + Spring boot with OAuth2 support for multiple SSO. (one at a time). In backend the token validation will be happen. I'm looking for a solution to use generic code/npm package in React to support multiple Authorization server. I just started with KeyCloak. (But shouldn't use KeyClock specific npm package in React, It should be generic library for support other Auth servers too). Is there a dependency (or) code sample for this??